# how to upload image at google cloud storage using app engine in django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I have performed the following steps, but the error at the bottom keeps showing up:

```
install pip install django-google-cloud-storage
```

```
add in setting.py file 

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'is_image_bucket'
```

> found Import Error - no module named storages

and also i have tried this tutorials
    https://libraries.io/pypi/django-google-cloud-storage

#### Configuration

On your `django settings.py` file you need to add the following settings

```
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = '/your_bucket_name' # the name of the bucket you have created from the google cloud storage console
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_URL = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket' #whatever the ulr for accessing your cloud storgage bucket
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_DEFAULT_CACHE_CONTROL = 'public, max-age: 7200' # default cache control headers for your files
And finally declare the file storage backend you will use on your settings.py file

   DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_google_cloud_storage.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

ModuleNotFoundError at /api/photo_docs/
No module named 'django_google_cloud_storage'

Comment: Can you please format your question a bit more clearly and add what you've tried and what did/didn't work, plus any code.

Comment: Could you please share your settings.py ? In order to get a better perspective  , I think that you are following [this tutorial](https://github.com/ingrammicro/django-gocs), right?

Comment: im following this tutorial https://libraries.io/pypi/django-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python 3, you should use pip3 instead of just pip. This should do the trick and fix the error.